# What is this aircraft, and what country makes it?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

[image]

What is this aircraft and what country produces it?

Source: Google Images

Comment: Please credit the source of your image.

Comment: "Google Images" is almost certainly not the source.

Comment: I saw it on Google Images, saved the image, then put it on the question.

Comment: @anonymous May I ask why you accepted the other answer and not mine? Just curious.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a [Raytheon Sentinel R1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raytheon_Sentinel), which is produced by [Raytheon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raytheon) (US) and [Bombardier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_Aerospace) (Canada). The aircraft in your picture is operated by the Royal Air Force.

[image: Sentinel R1]
<sup>(Image Source: [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raytheon_Sentinel#/media/File:Raf-sentinel-ZJ692-071023-27-16.jpg) - Author: Alan Radecki)</sup>

Answer (score 10):

This is a Raytheon Sentinel, built primarily for the United Kingdoms Royal Air Force.

In fact, the same aircraft is pictured on the Wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raytheon_Sentinel

Comment: @Andrew Notice the number on the engine... same aircraft.